# How to extend built-in objects in Javascript, For example Math?

Tags: javascript, binding, bind

Was learning **Call, Apply, Bind** trio.

Then tried this:

```
Math.__proto__.sum = function(arg1){var res=0; for(i in arg1) res+=arg1[i]; return res; };
Math.sum([1,2,3])
//Output: "6function (arg1){var res=0; for(i in arg1) res+=arg1[i]; return res; }"
```

Why does this output contains function defination attached with the sum output?

How do we extend a built-in object like Math in a project with such utility methods and use it all over?

Thanks :)

Comment: You can just say `Math.sum = function () { /* do stuff */}`

Comment: @mhodges It's all the same result.

Comment: You need to use `for...of` for arrays, not `for...in`. If you use `for...in`, it will grab you the properties and all of the prototype properties, which are 1, 2, 3, and the sum function. It calls `.toString()` on the sum function and concatinates it to the answer of summing the previous properties, which is why you get the output you are getting.

Comment: @mhodges, Hey simply **Math.sum** worked. But I'm looking for the answer why it did not work with **Math.__proto__.sum** approach.

But **for .. of** is a ES6+ feature isn't it?

Comment: Right, because Math.sum is not adding it to the prototype, and `Math.__proto__.sum` is. So when you iterate with `for...in`, when you add it to the prototype, it will grab it and concatinate it with your result. When you just do `Math.sum`, it does not add it to the prototype, therefore, does not show up in `for...in`. And yes, `for...of` is an ES6 feature. `.reduce()` or `.forEach()` will be just fine if you do not want to use ES6 features

Comment: Hey amazing, **for of** did work! So anyone who wants to do this before ES6+ will need huge workaround? And If am to get it worked in **Math__proto__.sum** approach, do I have to re-implement the **toString** method of the Math object? How expensive could that be?

Please write your answer as in an answer. I will mark that accepted. Also, if  possible, please explain how could someone extend as such and use a built-in object project-wide? 

Nice answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @edam you _do not_ want to implement `sum` as a member of `Math.__proto__`, first of all, because `__proto__` is an implementation-specific property and is not portable, and secondly because _it makes no sense_ for _every_ object to have a `sum()` member method. Keep in mind `Math.__proto__ === Object.prototype`, so you could do crazy things like `{}.sum()` or `[].sum()`, `/regexp/.sum()` or even `0..sum()`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, ha ha ha.. Now I see your point. Yes you're right; I definitely shouldn't do it.

Comment: @edam I wouldn't call using `.forEach()` or `.reduce()` a "huge workaround", but to each his own, I guess.

Comment: @edam Also, not going to write an answer because others have already captured the sentiment of what I am saying. I am just providing a little more detail as to *why* they are offering the solutions they're offering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic example of why you don't mess with `__proto__` (unless you absolutely *know* what you're doing). Attaching a function to `Object.prototype` as an enumerable property causes it to be iterated in your `for...in` loop since `Array` extends `Object`. This results in the function being concatenated to your sum and coerced to a string.

If you want to add functionality to `Math`, for most purposes, you can just assign directly to `Math`:

```
Math.sum = function() {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript allows you to modify native objects:

```js
Math.sayHello = function(friend) {
  alert('Hello there ' + friend);
}

Math.sayHello('buddy');
```

Of course this could soon be messy when you actually redefine methods.

```js
Math.ceil = function(x) {
  return parseInt(x, 10);
}

console.log(Math.ceil(4.9));
```

Comment: `Math.prototype` is undefined

Comment: Derp! Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to implement a method for `Math` in the same manner as `Math.max` which take the arguments and returns a folded result.

```js
Math.add = (...args) => args.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(Math.add(1, 2, 3));
console.log(Math.add(...[7, 8, 9]));
```

Only ES5

```js
Math.add = function () {
    var i = arguments.length,
        sum = 0;

    while (i--) {
        sum += arguments[i];
    }
    return sum;
};

console.log(Math.add(1, 2, 3));
console.log(Math.add.apply(null, [7, 8, 9]));
```

Comment: Hi @Nina, Very Nice! Could you implement it without using **array function notation**? And also can you please explain why mine didn't work? Is **args.reduce** a  ES6+ feature?

Comment: [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is ES5. which implementation do you need?

Comment: @edam Yours didn't work because you're using `for...in` instead of `for...of` on an array, and no, `Array.prototype.reduce` is not an ES6 feature - been around a long time.

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks for the addition of ES5 version :)